# Do multi-bit signals send/receive to/from pins of IC simultaneously?

Tags: discrete-signals

Supposing there is a 16-bit data bus between the CPU and the memory, I want to save 16-bit data 1000 0000 0000 0001 to memory with a given address. The data bus consists of 16 wires(I don't know the terminology for "wire") connecting between the D0~D15 pins of the CPU and the same name pins of the memory.

[image]

I wonder if the 16 signals corresponding to the 16-bit data do not arrive at pins of memory at the same time, e.g., the most significant bit 1(transfer via D15) arrives at the D15 pin of memory much slower than other signals transfer via D0~D14, will it lead a wrong number to be store at memory?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably a better fit for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ but I'll give is shot.

Most memory interfaces are clocked. The source sets up 0s and 1s on the data pins and once that's all stable, it sends a signal to the receiver that the data is now ready to be consumed. At that point the receiver reads all bits at once.

> (I don't know the terminology for "wire")

It's typically called lines.

> e.g., the most significant bit 1(transfer via D15) arrives at the D15 pin of memory much slower than other signals transfer via D0~D14,

Why would it be slower ? The pin drivers are all designed identical.

> will it lead a wrong number to be store at memory?

Not really. The source signals when all pins are ready.

Comment: That is if the *"source"* is also the host or **master** of the bus.  If a CPU is *reading* data from memory, there does not need to be a handshake from the memory, unless it's slow.  For fast RAM, the CPU put out and address, the bus clock goes high (or low), whatever means that the address and R/W lines are valid, and based on that, the memory has to respond correctly at the low (or high) edge of the clock.

Answer (score 0):

Your memory is missing the control signals.

As long as the setup and hold times of data bus is within specs for the write control signal to make a proper write then it will work.

If data changes during the time it is required to be stable then the write may be corrupted.

So if you have a fast write pulse, and long wiring, it may be that the data bus not fulfill the requirements for the write signal. In such cases it may be possible to add wait states so the data arrives at the chip and is stable for long enough before the write pulse.